# Find all Matches of Strings in a Column in a Second Dataframe and Return Matches in Adjacent Rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, *df1['Keyword']* and *df2['Description']* I've trying to find every instance of the strings found in a column in df1['Keyword'] that appear in df2['Description'] and return the matched strings in adjacent cols in df2.

**Desired Output**

```
df1['Keyword']      df2['Description']               df2['Match1']    df2['Match 2']   df3['Match 3']
apples              apples are tasty                 apples
bananas             apples and bananas are tasty     apples           bananas
oranges             oranges, lemons, apples          oranges          lemons           apples
lemons              cucumber
```

(I've labelled the match columns here, but they can be named anything).

**What I've tried:**

```
df2['Match'] = df2['Description'].apply(lambda x: lookup(x, df1['Keyword']))
```

This gets me most of the way there, but it only pulls out the first keyword it matches in the df2['Description'] and places it in a new colun called ['Match'] whereas I need to find every single match (ideally in an exact match).

Thanks for any help, just started to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
regex = r'|'.join(df1.Keyword)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2,
                (pd.DataFrame(df2.Description
                                 .str.findall(regex).to_list()))],
               axis='columns').fillna('')
```

Result:

```
   Keyword                   Description        0        1       2
0   apples              apples are tasty   apples                 
1  bananas  apples and bananas are tasty   apples  bananas        
2  oranges       oranges, lemons, apples  oranges   lemons  apples
3   lemons                      cucumber
```